# How to call undo even or any TinyMCE features by clicking my button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to make custom design editor using Jquery TinyMCE editor, I want to use my sidebar button for TinyMCE editor toolbar button like undo, redo, bold and italic etc, but I can't call that event by clicking my button. I have shared a screenshot of my custom editor and button area. If you have any editor to make this then use that Jquery Editor TinyMCE not mandatory for me.
Please suggest me if you have any solutions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2viWQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think undoManager can solve your issue, like that:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.undoManager.undo();
```

http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:property.tinymce.Editor.undoManager

For other command -

http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.execCommand

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('Bold');
```

Comment: Thank you very much